# Compare And Edit Excel Rows C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to iterate through and excel file row by row..
First checking if the rows first column has a Name in a list
If so then update the seventh column of that row to 0.

The code below doesn't crash and seems to be doing what I am asking it to do.

There are 2 issues...

1. After the code runs no changes are saved to the Excel file. I have tried several methods to .Save() and nothing takes. Could it be because I am using a the free version of VS?
2. I have roughly 150 names in the PersonsToExcludeMAIN and roughly 250 rows to compare too and the code take roughly 8 min to run. Why?

   ```
   DB_PATH = @"C:\Users\n\Downloads\Nick1.xlsx";
   File.SetAttributes(DB_PATH, FileAttributes.Normal);
   MyApp = new Excel.Application();
   MyApp.Visible = false;
   MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(DB_PATH);
   MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
   lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;

   //Get the used Range
   Excel.Range usedRange = MySheet.UsedRange;

   //Iterate the rows in the used range
   foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
   {
          //PersonsToExcludeMAIN has the Names Of all the People (in the "Name" property) in the DB_PATH (the excel file I am trying to edit) I want to set their Column "7" to "0"
          List<Person> tempList = PersonsToExcludeMAIN.Where(item => item.Name == (row.Columns[1].Value2.ToString())).ToList();

           if (tempList.Count > 0)
           {
            //This gets reached and seems to be executing properly
            row.Columns[7].Value2 = "0";
           }

   }

   //This Save() doesn't do anything
   MyBook.Save();
   MyBook.Close(true);
   MyApp.Quit();
   ```

Comment: You shouldn't use Interop for something like this. Use some library. SO has many examples. Then all your problems will go away.

Comment: @T.S. The data given is in excel files. Do I change the files to another format and then manipulate them?

Comment: No. Just load them with the given library or driver of your choice. Point is, data manipulation without loading `Excel.Application`. https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel + `microsoft.ace.oledb` allows you manipulate Excel data using ADO.net just like any table. + no need for excel installation, + no problem with server/web server/ mult instances deployment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Looking at the docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.save?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vsto-2017#Microsoft_Office_Tools_Excel_Workbook_Save)) for `Workbook.Save()` method, it has a remark that says

> The first time you save a workbook, use the SaveAs method to specify a name for the file.

Maybe that's the case?

2. I see in your code that you are creating the name list inside the `foreach` loop. I believe that's why it's taking too long. If you create it outside the loop, it might be faster.